# Must all cristoffel symbols vanish in suitable coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M $ be a manifold equipped with a torsion free linear connection. Let $m_0$ be a point in M. Must there exist a chart $\phi $ around $m_0$ such that all cristoffel symbols at $m_0$ of the  connection with respect to $\phi $  vanish?

Thank you

Comment: Only if the curvature is zero.

Comment: @AndersBeta: note "at $m_0$". I believe geodesic coordinates should generalize straightforwardly to an arbitrary torsion-free connection.

Comment: @Anthony Carapetis   so do you think it's impossible or possible to get such a chart ?

Comment: Possible. Look in a Riemannian geometry book for the construction of geodesic normal coordinates, then just check that everything works without needing a metric. You should just need to prove that the exponential mapping is a diffeomorphism in a small enough neighbourhood of $0 \in T_{m_0}M$, then define your chart by composing this with some linear isomorphism $\mathbb R^n \to T_{m_0} $.M

Comment: In the moving frame world, you can always construct locally a frame for a connection on *any* vector bundle so that the Christoffel symbols (with respect to that frame) vanish at a given point.

Comment: Yup! But not all frames come from charts, so a little bit more work is involved here. The torsion-free assumption will be crucial, since if there is non-zero torsion $T^i_{jk} = \Gamma^i_{[jk]}$ at a point, clearly $\Gamma$ cannot vanish there. With symmetry of $\Gamma$ as an assumption, $\Gamma(m_0) = 0$ should follow from the geodesic equation for lines through the origin and the polarization formula.

Comment: @Anthony: Well, since I alluded to a general vector bundle, of course I was not making any reference to charts on the manifold. I just threw that in for general information. :)

Comment: If the Christoffel symbols vanishes in a region, the curvature has to be zero in the whole region, not just at $m_0$. In the region where the Christoffel symbols vanish, the covariant derivatives along coordinate directions commute, which means the curvature is zero. You can always make the Christoffel symbols vanish at one point, but not in a whole region if the curvature is non-zero in that region.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Where in the proof would we need to use symmetry ?

Comment: As I said, you need symmetry so that you can apply the polarization identity; i.e. so that the vanishing of the quadratic form $v \mapsto \Gamma^i_{jk} v^j v^k$ implies $\Gamma = 0.$